# How do I change web-page color on HTML?

Tags: html

I pretty much just started HTML5 and I know a few tags, but I want to be able to change the web-page color. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Find where the `<body>` tag is and replace it with `<body style="background-color: yellow">`

Comment: Show your code first!

Comment: This site is used for specific questions only. We dont just give out free code. You need to explain, what you tried, and whats the problem. And, show the code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the body tag, and it should be like this: 
`<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">
</body>`

Comment: Not to mention that this type of things is usually modified with CSS. Although I told you the answer, I do not really believe that your question is suitable, as it can be easily found with a quick search. Stack Overflow is intended for errors or more difficult or specific doubts.